# How to reset map locator in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, location, reset

My map locator works but I am not sure how to reset the marker so that when the user geolocates it resets the position.  Currently, my code looks like this:

```
    //map locator 
    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

    function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("Vous êtes ici").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);


    function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
    // end of geolocator with marker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the latlng and radius:

```
var marker = null;
var circle = null;

//map locator 
map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy;

    if(!marker){
        marker = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
        circle = L.circle(e.latlng,radius).addTo(map);
    }else{
        marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        circle.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        circle.setRadius(radius);
    }

    marker.bindPopup("Vous êtes ici").openPopup();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I replaced the L.marker and L.circle with the code you gave and kept the rest.  It all seems to work great!